# Hide UIButton and not just remove visibility

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

I want to hide my UIButton in my swift 3 application.

Currently i set

```
cell.myButton.isHidden = true
```

That makes the Button not visible anymore, but the space the button would take is still taken.

How could i really hide the button?

I create the UIButton in a tableViewCell and set the constraints with SnapKit

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
cell.myButton.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: The Layout is crashed.

Comment: If you have other items constraint related to this button, sure it will crash.
You can fix this by adding another constraint to these related items to be related to super view.

Comment: But its also removed from the elements in table where it should stay.

Comment: If you want to show this button again, keep that new constraint you added to other items and make constraint to button width and set to 0 to hide and cell.layoutIfNeeded()

And set it's width value to show it again 
cell.layoutIfNeeded()

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `setNeedsLayout` to adjust the position of the subviews in your tableViewCell. When you set your buttonHide property in your tableViewCell class, also call `self.setNeedsLayout()`
Then your `viewDidLayoutSubview` will be triggered, in which you should set the frame of your tableViewCell's subviews.

Comment: i called cell.setNeedsLayout - but nothing changes.

Comment: @develth In your tableViewCell class, you need to override `viewDidLayoutSubview` and put all subviews at the right place(base on the value of your buttonHide property)

Answer (score 0):

You have various choices.

You can add constraints for the height and width of your button, wire them up as outlets, and set the constraints' constants to 0. That would make them zero-sized.

You can remove the button from it's superview as shown in @AymanKarram's answer, but you would need to keep a strong reference to it or it will be deallocated. (Try removing the weak qualifier on your @IBOutlet declaration of `myButton` as a test. That will cause the IBOutlet to hold a strong reference.)

Comment: I didn´t created the View via the Storyboard so i do not have any @IBOutlets
Any possibility to keep the items where i need that button with AymanKarram´s answer?

Comment: Create an instance variable and save your button in that.

Comment: The instance variable will keep an owning reference to the button so it doesn't get deallocated when you remove the button from it's superview.

Answer (score -2):

How about setting the height for that tableView row as 0?

Comment: I have other elements in the tableView row that needs to be shown.

Comment: @develth and if you set a height constraint equal to 0 to the button? If you were using Storyboard constraints, I would tell you to create an outlet for the height constraint and setting the constant to 0 when you wanted to hide the button. But as you're using SnapKit, maybe you can set again the button constraints with height = 0.